# In fluent-ffmpeg, how do you include multiple video filters?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

The code below adds the watermark but ignores the scaling.
How do you include multiple video filters in fluent-ffmpeg?

```js
ffmpeg(inputFileName)
  .inputOptions(['-safe 0', '-f concat'])
  .outputOptions([
    '-filter:v scale=w=1280:h=720',
    "-filter:v drawtext=text='watermarkText':x=W-150:y=H-th-10:fontsize=32:fontcolor=white",
    '-crf 10'
  ])
  .save('output.mp4');
```

I tried these formats as well inside `.outputOptions([])` to no avail: 
`'-filter:v <param1>, <param2>'` 
`'-filter:v <param1>; <param2>'` 
`'-filter:v', '<param1>', '<param2>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can just separate the two filters using a comma:

```python
ffmpeg(inputFileName)
  .inputOptions(['-safe 0', '-f concat'])
  .outputOptions(["-filter:v scale=w=1280:h=720,drawtext=text='watermarkText':x=W-150:y=H-th-10:fontsize=32:fontcolor=white",
    '-crf 10'
  ])
  .save('output.mp4');
```

I can't test it with `fluent-ffmpeg`, but this is the `ffmpeg` command line syntax.

Testing using command line:

- Generate synthetic input video file:

  ```
  ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=192x108:rate=1 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 input.avi
  ```
- Scale to 1280x720 and draw text (using large green text):

  ```
  ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -filter:v scale=w=1280:h=720,drawtext=text='watermarkText':x=W/2:y=H-th-10:fontsize=72:fontcolor=green -vcodec libx264 -crf 10 output.mp4
  ```

I am not sure about the correctness of `'-f concat'` argument, and you also missed the video codec specification.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. For my purposes, I needed to add padding to the video as well in order for it to add the text outside the original video.